# Meaning of "test_data: n_test" in python 3.8

Tags: python, if-statement

I am following a tutorial on Neural_Networks and it uses python2.7 and the line of code I am confused with is the if statement  '''
if test_data: n_test = len(test_data)
''' and I ever came across this syntax in python 3.8 and please explain me what does test_data: n_test means. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `if` statement in python, it checks if `test_data` exists and if exists then sets the value of the variable `n_data` to the string length of `test_data` variable.

Comment: Thank You. I understood now and the main reason for my confusion is that in that turtorial he didnt indented the condition properly that needs to be exucuted when the if statment satisfies. He have that n_test = len(test_data) beside semi clon ":" without entering into a new line. Thank you so much for answering it helped me a lot

Comment: Indentation is not required at all here... If you have found the answer helpful then click The big tick mark and click the ^ looking button to upvote and accept it as the answer of the question